# How can I get the image name after I click on it?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a project. I am storing images and informations about them.
I would like to that, if I click on an image, show me the correct image's infos.
How can I do this with sessions?

The page which displays the images:

```
<a href="movieinfos.php?img='<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['top1']; ?>'">
<?php include "connection.php";
session_start();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT poster,name FROM movies ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
while ($top = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $_SESSION['top1'] = $top['poster'];
    $_SESSION['moviename'] = $top['name'];
}
    echo "<img src='".$_SESSION['top1']."' height='150' width='100'>";
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo $_SESSION['moviename'];
?>       
    <br>
    </a>
```

And the film info page:

```
<?php session_start(); include "connection.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT poster,name FROM filmek WHERE boritokep = '".$_GET['img'].".png'");
while ($f = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $_SESSION['mimg'] = $f['poster'];
    $_SESSION['mname'] = $f['name'];
}
echo "<img src='".$_SESSION['mimg']."' height='250' width='180'>";
?>
```

Thanks for your helps!!

Comment: Maybe you try a workaround and put a link to a redirect PHP file on it. Save the session and redirect (via header) directly to the image. The user won't notice it with fast(er) internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working version:

I use links in the images:

```
<?php session_start();
echo "<a href=\"filminfo.php?id=".$id."\">";
echo "<img src='".$_SESSION['top1']."' height='150' width='100'>";
echo "</a>";
?>
```

And in the film info page I select films with that's ids:

```
<?php session_start(); include "connection.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT poster,name FROM films WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'");
while ($f = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $_SESSION['mimg'] = $f['poster'];
    $_SESSION['mname'] = $f['name'];
}
echo "<img src='".$_SESSION['mimg']."' height='250' width='180'>";
echo "$_SESSION['mname']";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the answer but I cant comment yet nor can show you an example code since I am at my iphone
But uhm for each record in your table you say rewrite the session
This will mean you will NEVER get the correct output as you want to
As you click an img I assume the image is shown by id like
?img='id'

On this way get your image
Filter (where) on id (the given img id)
Then simply make a select all query and loop through it
Now just get the info that you want to show and show it...

Comment: Is it possible if I click on an image, stores it's path in a variable or a session?
And I would be able to list the infos about that. And when I click another image the variable or the session will owerwrite.

Comment: Well ye it is possible but I don't see the use of it just use it like a $_GET[] and gain your info through that session isn't needed in this way I think it's even quiet useless for getting image info...

Comment: Then how can I store the clicked image name insted of $_GET[]?

Comment: I think you can also use a form method="POST" action="page to get" use the hidden key as imgID="{id of the image}" and the submit key as image and on clicked you use $_POST['hiddenkeyID/NAME'] this is a better way to do it in my opinion using sessions is totally useless and no one would like it... This is probably the only way you can do it properly without any other language than php & html